# VS2010 Calculation

Tags: c#

I am looking to calculate a value on a button click in VS2010 C#.

The code below is not working and gives errors but essentially this is what i am after:

If dgvFormFields.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value has a number (for example 17.85), when the button is clicked i want dgvFormFields.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value to show what is 10% tax value.  This is determined by dgvFormFields.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value - (dgvFormFields.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value/1.1)

```
public void btnGST_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (dgvFormFields.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
           int32 gstvalue = -1;
           try
           {
               gstvalue = (dgvFormFields.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value);
           }
        dgvFormFields.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value = (gstvalue - (gstvalue / 1.1));
        }
}
```

Comment: So what is the error?  What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: two errors.  1 is "expected catch or finally"  at dgvFormFields.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value = (gstvalue - (gstvalue / 1.1));  the other is "the type or namespace name 'int32' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" at "int32 gstvalue = -1;"

Comment: Please update your question with the details and make it clearer

Comment: Every `try` needs to be paired with a `catch` and/or `finally`. And what is `int32` supposed to be? just use `int` (which is an alias for `System.Int32`)?

Comment: hi unholy,i copied the setup from another part of the application code.  The cell has a number in it and the error without it is "Cannot implicitly convert 'object' to 'int' An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)